# backupy output ANSI color codes doesn't work when call by Python os.system

Tags: python, windows-terminal

[BackuPy](https://github.com/elesiuta/backupy) outputs color messages when executing from `cmd.exe` in Windows10. However if I invoke it from Python `os.system` as following:

```
os.system(f'backupy --noprompt {env.workdrive}hlao {env.usbdrive}hlao')
```

the ANSI color codes (ex:`?[94m`) doesn't change the text color but display code literal directly, disturbing the original messages as following:

```
?[94mScanning files on source:
E:\hlao?[0m
```

How to solve this problem?

ps: BackuPy is a backup tools written by Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind forgoing colour messages, you can use the flag `--nocolour` to omit the codes.

If you still want coloured messages, here's a few things you can try. (I'm not on Windows right now to test these, but it is probably due to os.system using the system shell given by the Windows environment variable COMSPEC, which is probably an instance of cmd.exe without colour codes enabled)

```
subprocess.run(['backupy', '--noprompt', f'{env.workdrive}hlao', f'{env.usbdrive}hlao']), shell=False)
```

```
import backupy
backupy.run({'noprompt': True, 'source': f'{env.workdrive}hlao', 'dest': f'{env.usbdrive}hlao'})
```

Also try it in another terminal with better colour support if possible, such as the New Windows Terminal.